# Awk to grab colo(u)r codes from CSS files aka School me in Awk

Tags: css, regex, awk

Nice and (hopefully) easy. I am trying to work out how to grab the variable #XXX from a text file (css file) containing strings like

> `hr { margin: 18px 0 17px; border-color: #ccc; }`
>
> `h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover { color: #001100; }`

Which I would like to return as

> `ccc`
>
> `001100`

The plan then is to throw this through sort and uniq and the end up with a defining colourscheme for the page.

Basically, I can't work out how to go from matching /color:#...[...]/ to just printing out the wildcarded sections.

Comment: Duh, thankyou for pointing that out, I oiginally only had examples of trirgb (...) and thought that I should add a hexrgb(.....) while I'm here.

Comment: Wups, haha. I totally overlooked the awk part of things! Carry on, gentlemen :)

Comment: Well if you can think of a better way of doing it I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/color/ s/.*color: *#\([^;]\+\);.*/\1/p' css_file
```

You could add some more optional whitespace:

```
sed -n '/color/ s/.*color:[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*\([[:xdigit:]]\+\)[[:space:]]*;.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Almost perfect, the second [[:space:]] needed to be made optional, and clause extended to restrict to [[:xdigit:]], but thanks!
Final answer I use is sed -n '/color/ s/.*color:[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*\([[:xdigit:]]\+\)[[:space:]]*;.*/\1/p'

Answer (score 1):

```
{ 
  RS = "[^ ]*color[ \t\r\n\f]*:[ \t\r\n\f]*" ;

  if (NR > 1) {
    match($0, "#[0-9A-Fa-f]+|rgb.*\)|[a-zA-Z]+") ;

    if (RSTART != 0)
      str = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) ;
      gsub("[ \t\r\n\f]", "", str) ;
      print str ;
  }
}
```

Just tried to create bullet-proof and robust AWK code. Not one-liner, but can survive even in some seriously mess up input.

Test input:

```
    hr { margin: 18px 0 17px; border-color: 
#ccc; }

    h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover { color: rgb ( 123, 

123, 123) }

    h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover { color: red }

    h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover { color: #001100; }
```

Output:

```
#ccc
rgb(123,123,123)
red
#001100
```

Answer (score 0):

here's 2 possible (and easier to read) ways with awk

```
awk -F"#" '/color/{sub(";.*","",$NF);print $NF}' file

awk -vFS="#|; *}" '/color/{print $2}' file
```

Comment: possible and easier,but more fragile; 
I quite like the first one.
in the second case, your solution correctly operates for the example case, but

"p { margin: 18px 0 17px; background-color: #ccc; color:#123}"

would be missed, as would 

"p { margin: 18px 0 17px; background-color: #ccc; color:#123} h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover { color: #001100; }"

Cheers anyway!